# page-router-outlet inside tabView in lazy loaded component

Tags: angular, routes, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, tabview

I want to add `page-router-outlet` to nativescript angular lazy loaded component.
this is my code please I don't see what is worng here.
(with router-outlet this is working but I need page)

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "home", loadChildren: () => import("~/app/home/home.module").then((m) => m.HomeModule) },
    { path: "users", loadChildren: () => import("~/app/users/users.module").then((m) => m.UsersModule) }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

users-routing.module.ts (the lazyloaded module routing)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { OrderClosingComponent } from './order-closing/order-closing.component';
import { ChoseMethodComponent } from './chose-method/chose-method.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path:"",redirectTo:"main",pathMatch:"full"},
  {path:"main", component:MainComponent,children:[
    {path:'choose',component:ChoseMethodComponent},
    {path:'orderClosing/:type',component:OrderClosingComponent } 
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class UsersRoutingModule { }
```

main.component.ts

```
<TabView selectedIndex="1" androidOffscreenTabLimit="1" effectiveMarginTop="100" androidTabsPosition="top" tabBackgroundColor="#4094a7" selectedTabTextColor="white" tabTextFontSize="17" androidSelectedTabHighlightColor="#eeeeee">
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'details'}">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="user details" textWrap="true" class="m-15 h2 text-left" color="black"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'do it'}">
        <StackLayout>
       <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet> <!--here is the problem-->
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

Comment: what about changing <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet> to <router-outlet></router-outlet> ?

Comment: @FrankAdrian I want the <page-router-outlet> because I need that the inner navigation will be saved in the history